# How to avoid adding duplicate data in Scrapy using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, web-scraping, pymongo, scrapy

I want to avoid adding duplicate data and just 1) update one field (number of views) or 2) all the fields that had changed in the website. To do so I'm using an ID (origin_id) that I have found in the website that I'm scraping.

Pipelines

```
class MongoDBPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
        settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
        settings['MONGODB_PORT']
    )
    db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
    self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    valid = True
    for data in item:
        if not data:
            valid = False
            raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
    if valid:
        # Update item if it is in the database and insert otherwise.
        self.collection.update({'origin_id': item['origin_id']}, dict(item), upsert=True)
    return item
```

MongoDB record

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59725e919a1a6b7f0350027a"),
    "origin_id" : "12256699",
    "views":"556",
    "url":"...",
    "title":"...",
}
```

Please let me know if you want more details ...

Comment: So what is the problem? These are "upserts". By nature it either updates the existing data based on the information in the query or "creates" where that query results in nothing being found. So it's really unclear what your problem is. If any problem at all.

Comment: For example the number of views it's not getting updated

Comment: All you are doing is sending the result of `dict(item)` and overwriting anything that was found. What are you expecting? What does this have to do with duplicates? If you come here to ask questions you need to be "very specific" and show an expected result and make it possible for people to reproduce. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: All I want is not overwriting an existing MongoDB record. So based on the origin_id if the item is already exist I want to just update the other fields such as number of views and not overwriting them but I don't know how to change MongoDBPipeline code to do that (update item if it is already in the database and insert otherwise.).

Comment: @geek-tech I just really don't understand this requirement - *I want to just update the other fields such as number of views and not overwriting them*. Can you clarify this? Or you want to just update *specific* fields instead of whole document? If so, take a look in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-specific-fields).

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `views` field by `1` if the `origin_id` exists in the document.

**Note that** you can only *set* the other fields as they hold non-numeric values.

This is also necessary in order to skip an extra query that checks if a document with that `origin_id` exists in the collection.

```
self.collection.update({
   'origin_id': item['origin_id']},
    {
        '$set': {'url': item['url'], 'title': item['title']},
        '$inc': {'views': 1}
    }
}, 
upsert=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... but I get the number of views directly from the site I'm scraping. Example: let's assume the number of views was 555 in the document (first time scraped the content), then when I scraped the same content the number of views became 799! So how can I overwrite the past number of views that is in the document? Please help

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to overwrite data for an id that already exists. I don't think you need to increment the views for that. You can write that in set. How about `'$set': {'url': item['url'], 'title': item['title'], 'views': item['views']}`? You should remove the increment query as well

Comment: That's what I want but yet still not updating the number of views! BTW I don't want to overwrite the whole data since just the number of views that is getting updated from the site that I'm scraping ...